# Listen to key press in .NET console app including Caps/Numlock in cross-platform way

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application

`Console.ReadKey(true)` does not read CapsLock / NumLock key presses.

I've seen some solutions doing native calls to Windows APIs but the solution then does not work on Linux/macOS.

Is there a cross-platform native way of doing this?

What I did now is having a thread that's checking `Console.CapsLock` and `Console.NumberLock` and comparing with latest saved state like every 100 ms. However it feels super hacky, plus they're only supported on Windows. Plus there's no `Console.ScrollLock`. I see that even [`System.ConsoleKey`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/consolekey.cs) has commented out some keys such as caps lock and numlock that I'm interested in, so .NET implementation lacks definitions for them.

What would you suggest as best option for going forward?

Comment: Console is line-oriented, it deals with complete lines or files of text. If you want to deal with UI events like keypresses you should use Xamarin or MAUI.

Comment: @DourHighArch you're definitely right, I learn its design by hard way now. I'm actually building a small UI to have an own small cross-platform applications that would work on my Ubuntu as well.